# Shall I install Visual Studio under C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86)?

Tags: visual-studio, 32bit-64bit

The development environmeng is x86, and the target is to compile .EXE that for both 32-bit or 64-bit Windows systems. Which folder shall I install? Seems the default installation folder is C:\programs files (x86), though I'm on a 64-bits Windows 7 OS. what's the difference on either one to install?

Comment: A tip so you will experience less misery: keep the default. The reason why it installs in the x86 Program Files is because the IDE and most tools are 32-bit applications. There are native 64-bit compilers, but these are also installed in the x86 Program Files. Don't ask me why their toolchain setup is so incredibly confusing and complicated.

Comment: @rubenvb yeah that's where I'm putting it, x86...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio is a 32-bit program so just let it install where it wants to.

You can still develop and debug 64-bit programs though, those things are orthogonal.

Comment: That's an invalid analogy and in any case I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I used some stupid SDK (e.g. ADS) which doesn't work with path including '()', and I wast a lot of time to find the problem.
I you have such kind SDK to use, do not install it in C:\programs files (x86).